# memory leak and instance variables

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void) getAccounts {

    self.selAccounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://localhost//listaccts"];
    self.processor=[[AsynConnectionProcessorController alloc] init];
    self.processor.delegate=self;
    self.processor.server=self.server;
    [processor createRequestfromURL:url];



}
```

This method is causing memory leak when invoked. Now if I replace this with below

```
-(void) getAccounts {
        [accounts release];

    self.selAccounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   

    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://localhost//listaccts"];
    self.processor=[[AsynConnectionProcessorController alloc] init];
    self.processor.delegate=self;
    self.processor.server=self.server;
    [processor createRequestfromURL:url];



}
```

I am getting memory leak if I invoke this method second time as a result of viewcontroller beong popped from stack.

Why does this leak? accounts is an insyance variable with declration like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *accounts;
```

Can't I assume that there won't be memory leak if I use setter via self.accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong

```
self.accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

the setter already does a retain, since you specified that in the property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *accounts;
```

you should rewrite it like this

```
   NSMutableArray arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   self.accounts = arr;
   [arr release];
```

or alternatively:

```
   self.accounts = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

EDIT: removed 'non preferred' - was subjective.

Comment: Why is `-autorelease` less preferred?

Comment: It isn't less preferred;  it is a premature optimization.

Comment: thank you, I see the error now. Do I need to use self each time I use the variable like : self.processor.delegate=self;
    self.processor.server=self.server;
    [processor createRequestfromURL:url];

Comment: either that or use the [[self processor] setDelegate:...] form - it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Bavarious the reason for this is that on the iPhone you typically would like to avoid using autorelease objects if you can handle it with "normal" allocated objects instead. If you have lots of autorelease objects you can experience something similar to memleaks if the pool is never drained/released.

Comment: @AndersK. @bbum But since frameworks (Apple’s and others) make use of autoreleased objects, it makes more sense to push/pop autorelease pools than use release ASAP. I have the impression that not using `-autorelease` gives a misleading sense of control over allocations in most situations.

Comment: @Bavarious, well yes I think having good control of the pool is essential in any case, but why use an autorelease object if you don't really need it? (IMHO)